# I cannot delete Devel generated content because I get an error about a not existing table

Tags: 8, database

I'm trying to delete some generated content but I get an unhandled exception in the log.

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.url_alias' doesn't exist: SELECT u.pid AS pid FROM {url_alias} u WHERE (source = :db_condition_placeholder_0) OR (source LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_1 ESCAPE '\'); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => /node/178 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => /node/178/% ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->delete() (line 794 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

The site is running on Drupal 8.8.0, and I installed the Pathauto module version 8.x-1.3.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by updating module Pathauto to 1.6 apparently the version I was using (1.3) had a compatibility issue with Drupal 8.8.0 on how path aliases are being handled now.